# c# graphics wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing a small project of my own - A Fractal Generator.

Would th einbuilt graphics of C# be adequate or would WPF be preferable?  I've never had a look at WPF, is it complicated and is it worthwhile learning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, WPF is

[perfectly](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/1072-mandelbrot-zoomer-in-wpf.html)

[fine](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2010/07/10/oh-shiny-animated-mandelbrot-shader-effect/)

[for](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Fractals.aspx)

[this task](http://www.google.com/search?q=fractals+with+wpf).

WPF was designed to replace *GDI+/System.Drawing*, so it contains most of the low level bitmap stuff you would expect (only this time with hardware accelleration) which can mostly be found in the namespace [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx).

The only API that might be superior in terms of functionality and performance (but not necessarily ease of use) could be the new [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370990%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Some great links there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is more about creating the overall UI for the application, with rich integration between the data and the visualization.  For the purpose of actually generating your fractal, it won't matter whether you use WPF, although the way you display the result in the UI will differ in WPF vs. WinForms.  In either case, you're probably going to want to output directly to a locked Bitmap buffer.

If you have more experience with WinForms, I'd recommend using that for now, so that you can focus on the application code.  WPF is worth learning, but it definitely has a learning curve.

Comment: Yeah, I do have more experience with WinForms and the project is only to gain more experience using basic graphics, so will give that a try and then move onto WPF for my next project.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is a GUI framework, not a graphic framework.

For a fractal generator, all you need is a way to display or write on disk an array of pixels. System.Drawing is more than enought.

Now, if you need advanced graphical interface to surround that, by all means, go for WPF.

Comment: It serves me well as an advanced graphics framework using StreamGeometry and WritableBitmap for example.